# What does π[v] ←u step mean in Prims algorithm for minimum spanning tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

In this [MIT video regarding Prims algorithm for minimum spanniing tree](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-16-greedy-algorithms-minimum-spanning-trees/) the professor explains `π[v] ←u` at time 71:16 seconds . But I do not understand why we need this step . What does this notation  `π[v] ←u` mean actually ? Also what does the last line in the algorithm that follows mean ?
The entire algorithm given in the source is as follows :

```
Q←V
key[v] ←∞for all v∈V
key[s] ←0for some arbitrary s∈V
while Q≠∅
 do u←EXTRACT-MIN(Q)
   foreach v∈Adj[u]
    do ifv∈Qand w(u, v) < key[v]
      then key[v] ←w(u, v)⊳DECREASE-KEY
           π[v] ←u

At the end, {(v, π[v])}forms the MST
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`π` is just any old array variable. So this line of code isn’t really different from the other assignments.

What it *does* in the algorithm however is save the *predecessor* node of the current node. `π` is sometimes also called the *predecessor function* because for any given node `n`, `π[n]` gives you the predecessor of that node (after the algorithm has completed).

So `π` can be used to reconstruct the path (= the edges of the spanning tree) found by Prim’s algorithm.

Comment: you said "π is just any old array variable" .Why does he not access the array with π[someIndex] then ?

Comment: @Geek Ok, it’s an [*associative array*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). But the same is true for `key` and `Adj` in your code. An indexed array is simply a special case of an associative array in which the indexers are integers from 0 to N. Most programming languages use “array” to mean the latter, i.e. “associative array indexed by an integer from 0 to N” but this algorithm uses a more general definition.

Comment: Can you please explain what the notation in the last line mean ?

Comment: @Geek As close as I can make it out, it’s an error in the pseudocode. It should actually read “At the end, (`v`, `π`) forms the MST”. This simply means that the MST is completely described by giving the node `v` and the predecessor function `π` (i.e. the tuple (`v`, `π`)). But even that is a bit unconventional … as far as I remember, the MST is usually described as a subgraph, i.e. by a set of nodes and vertices (but it can be shown that these two forms are in fact equivalent).